# Getting all queue name of AWS MQ using amqp10 npm Module?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, activemq-classic

I am using amqp10 npm module in dealing with AMQ MQ as they are no methods defined in their AWS SDK for MQ through which I can consume and publish the message to the queue.

Now, I need to get all queue names of my AWS MQ broker and I am unable to find any method which is defined in amqp10 npm module.

Can someone please help me on this, or is there any other npm module which I need to use?

Thanks